# IEnumrator for SetActive + Wait not working right

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have this simple coroutine:

```
    public IEnumerator ConfirmationBox()
    {
        confirmationPrompt.SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        confirmationPrompt.SetActive(false);
    }
```

When I active it, the object (just an image) pops up as intended, but it doesn't go away.

Any ideas how can this be fixed?

Comment: How are you invoking this coroutine?

Comment: If `confirmationPrompt` is pointing to the `GameObject` this script is on or a parent of it, it will stop any coroutines the script started.

Comment: The script is not on the confirmationPrompt object.
This is one place it is being called at for example:
```
public void VolumeApply()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("masterVolume", AudioListener.volume);
        StartCoroutine(ConfirmationBox());
    }
```
And the confirmationPrompt itself is given to the script from Unity.

I should mention that it has worked previously, but suddenly stopped when I simply changed the color of the object. But after reverting still didn't work...

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Comment: `confirmationPrompt` is not maybe this very same object itself or any of its parents by accident?

Answer (score 0):

You're using
StartCoroutine("ConfirmationBox");
to Invoke this method. Are you?

Comment: I'm using this: StartCoroutine(ConfirmationBox());

Comment: Then something else is keeping it active.